# Trouble with arrays and structs from input file

Tags: c++

I am working on this problem for a college course and I'm unsure why it isn't working. I thought I had everything setup correctly, but when I try running the program the file won't open on the first attempt at inputting the file name and when I input it again I get an "Exception Thrown" error in the "xmemory" part that I have no idea what any of it means.

The input file that the program is taking data from is just a text file with the following data:

```
201742 Sponge Bob 82.6
201701 Patrick Star 14.1
201753 Squidward Tentacles 85.43
201744 Sandy Squirrel 75.61
201700 Plankton Plank 100.0
```

The final output of the program should display the highest and lowest grade with the students first and last name, the average score, and the number of students tested. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
// Zane Richards
// Lab 10 Q2
// 4/6/2020

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct student {
    int ID;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    float grade;
};

void maxGradeFunc(struct student* s, int size)
{
    float maxGrade = 0;
    string firstName, lastName; 

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
    {
        if (s[i].grade > maxGrade)
        {
            maxGrade = s[i].grade;
            firstName = s[i].firstName; 
            lastName = s[i].lastName; 
        }
    }

    cout << "Maximum grade is " << maxGrade << endl;
    cout << "The name of the student with the grade is: " << firstName << " " << lastName << endl;
} 

void minGradeFunc(struct student* s, int size)
{
    float minGrade = 999;
    string firstName, lastName;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
    {
        if (s[i].grade < minGrade) 
        {
            minGrade = s[i].grade;
            firstName = s[i].firstName;
            lastName = s[i].lastName;
        }
    }

    cout << "Maximum grade is " << minGrade << endl;
    cout << "The name of the student with the grade is: " << firstName << " " << lastName << endl;
}


void avgGradeFunc(struct student* s, int size)
{
    float sum = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
    {
        sum += s[i].grade;
    }

    float avg = sum / size; 
    cout << "Avearge grade is " << avg << endl;
    cout << "The total number of students are: " << sum << " students" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    string fileName = "";
    struct student s[5]; 
    int ID; 
    string firstName, lastName; 
    float grade;
    int i = 0;

    cout << "Please enter the input file name: "; //File is named "Student.txt"
    cin >> fileName; 

    while (!inFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Sorry, the file did not open. \nTry again, or type \"cancel\" to quit: ";
        cin >> fileName;
        if (fileName == "cancel") {
            cout << "Cancelling..." << endl;
            break;
        }
        else {
            inFile.open(fileName);
        }
    }

    while (inFile.is_open()) {

        inFile >> ID; 

        s[i].ID = ID;
        inFile >> firstName;
        s[i].firstName = firstName;


        inFile >> lastName;
        s[i].lastName = lastName;


        inFile >> grade;
        s[i].grade = grade;
        i++;
    }

    maxGradeFunc(s, 5); 
    minGradeFunc(s, 5);
    avgGradeFunc(s, 5);
    return 0;

}
```

Here is the error code I'm getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i35Oq.png

Comment: after inputting the name of the file from the user, why do you then immediately check if inFile is open? You never actually attempted to open the file the first time. Also, instead of writing "I got an exception thrown error in the xmemory part but I have no idea what it means", please just copy and paste the error you get exactly how it appears into the question. You don't need to describe errors, just post exactly what the error is, please.

Comment: Worse you don't want to describe errors. If you don't already know what the error means, how can you be sure you haven''t left out the information that will allow someone who does know what it means to answer in seconds?

Comment: Change your loop of !file.isopen() to !file cause you want to check if it exists.  you can also check if the file is currently in use but this logic makes it so the program never runs...  After this fix I then got output issues.

Your input strategy using ">>" goes character by character as well not full strings

Comment: There is no first attempt at opening the file. Which is why you always see the error message.

Comment: Then your second loop is an infinte loop because the file is open and that never changes, so the loop goes on for ever (until you program crashes).

Comment: Okay I got rid of the whole part of the code that allowed multiple  attempts to write the file name and changed it to just a simple "inFile.open(fileName)" and it solved the problem, must have been an issue with that which caused the error. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue, deleted the code that allowed for multiple attempts, and changed it to just open the file and that fixed it. Thanks for the help everyone, much appreciated!